# To what degree can normality be violated for one way anova?

Tags: anova, normality-assumption, kruskal-wallis-test

i want to do anova but my data is not normal? i can run Kruskal-Wallis H test instead but the post hoc test for Kruskal-Wallis is not easily found.the skewness is 1.33 and kurtosis .536 of my data- can i still use anova and tukey hsd?

also i convert the data into percentage.Under 5 groups i collected 1000 data but hence the sample was not equal for 7 area i convert them into percentage,Which made 1000 data into 35 data. 
What should i do?

Comment: Welcome Shariar, you should try to clarify your question to make it more likely that you will attract an answer. You should try to format it in a way that make it easier to take in for the reader.

Comment: You description of your data and what you did to the values is unclear. If you only have 35 observations, would you be able to show us what you have, describe what numbers you started with and attempt to explain the calculations you did? Note also that there are numerous posts on site regarding [post hoc for Kruskal-Wallis](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Kruskal+wallis+post+hoc), but if your data are percentages there may be other choices that might do better.

Comment: Note that with percentages (I assume from your mention of area that these are continuous percentages rather than count proportions) normality isn't your only issue - heteroskedasticity may be more important.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! i am clearing my  question in another new question....